# Error in Angular project, routing/navigation, when I click on a title to show a movie I don't get my object

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In my angular project where I want to be able to push on a movie title and then get the movie details showed aint working, I really can't see what I'm doing wrong or what I havent done for that matter.

I'm new to this so i guess i might have a lot of "errors" in my project but I tried all I can to find a way to solve my problem without a solution.

there is some outcomment code to where I tried some ideas but didn't want to remove it so i just outcommet the code if you guys wonder :)

I do get my movies out as I want and showed but when I push on a title where I want to get a new component to show the movie details I don't get anything expect the static html as you can see in the file :/

I hope someone can help me out.

**movie.service.ts looks like this**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

import { Movie } from './shared/Movie';

interface IMovieData {results : Movie[];}
export interface IVideoData {results : IVideo[];}
export interface IVideo {'id': string; 'key':string; 'name':string; 'site': string; 'type':string; }

@Injectable()
export class MovieService {

  private movie : any;
  private key : string;

  constructor(private http : Http) { }

  public getMovies(): Observable<Response>{
    return this.http.get("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=skyfall&api_key=mykey");
  }

  public getMovie(title : string) : Observable<Movie[]> {
    return this.http.get("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=" + title + "&api_key=mykey")
    .map(response => {
      const data : IMovieData = response.json();
      return data.results.filter(movie => movie.poster_path !== null).map(movie => 
        {return <Movie>{'id' : movie.id,
                        'title' : movie.title,
                        'poster_path' : "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185_and_h278_bestv2"+movie.poster_path, 
                        'adult' : movie.adult,
                        'overview' : movie.overview,
                        'release_date' : movie.release_date,
                        'genres' : movie.genres,
                        'vote_average' : movie.vote_average }})

    })
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts looks like this**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
//import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MovielistComponent } from './movielist/movielist.component';
import { SearchService } from './searchservice/searchservice.module';
import { MoviedetailComponent } from './moviedetail/moviedetail.component';
import { MovieService } from './movie.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MovielistComponent,
    MoviedetailComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
      path: 'movielist',
      component: MovielistComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'moviedetail/:title', 
        component: MoviedetailComponent
      }
    ])
    //NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [SearchService, MovieService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts looks like this**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import  'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { SearchService } from './searchservice/searchservice.module';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { MovieService } from './movie.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [SearchService, MovieService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  results: Object;
  searchTerm$ = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private searchService: SearchService) {
    this.searchService.search(this.searchTerm$)
      .subscribe(results => {
        this.results = results.results;
      });
  }
}
```

**Movie.ts**

```
export interface Movie {
    id : number;
    poster_path : string;
    adult : boolean;
    overview : string;
    title : string;
    release_date : string;
    genres : string;
    vote_average : string;
}
```

**movielist.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import  'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Movie } from '../Shared/Movie';
import { MovieService } from '../movie.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movielist',
  templateUrl: './movielist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movielist.component.css']
})
export class MovielistComponent implements OnInit {

  private apiUrl = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?primary_release_date.gte=2014-09-15&primary_release_date.lte=2014-10-22&api_key=dbd9bb30692c83bcd53628df049f31ef';
  data: any = {};
  /*private movies : Movie[]; */

  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private movieService : MovieService, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
              )
  {
    console.log('Hello Fellow User');
    this.getContacts();
    this.getData();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  }

  getContacts(){
    this.getData().subscribe(data => {console.log(data);
    this.data = data})
  }
  public onSelect(result : Movie){
    this.router.navigate(['/moviedetail', result.title]);
  }
}
```

**movielist.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">

            <ng-container *ngFor="let result of data.results">
                <div class="moviebox">
                    <h5>{{result.title}}</h5>
                    <p>{{result.overview}}</p>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </ng-container>

        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <h3>Mid col</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col">

            <div class="movies">
                <ul class="movies">
                    <li *ngFor="let result of data.results" [class.selected]="result === selectedMovie" (click)="onSelect(result)">
                        <span>{{result.title}} </span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**moviedetail component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import  'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Movie } from '../Shared/Movie';
import { MovieService } from '../movie.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-moviedetail',
  templateUrl: './moviedetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./moviedetail.component.css']
})
export class MoviedetailComponent implements OnInit {

  /*private apiUrl = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?primary_release_date.gte=2014-09-15&primary_release_date.lte=2014-10-22&api_key=mykey';
  data: any = {};*/
  public movie : Movie;

  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private movieService : MovieService, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
              )
  {/*
    console.log('Hello Fellow User');
    this.getContacts();
    this.getData();*/
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.movie = this.movieService.getMovie(this.route.snapshot.params['title']);
  }


  public gotoMovies(){
    this.router.navigate(['/movielist']);
  }

  /*
  getData() {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  }

  getContacts(){
    this.getData().subscribe(data => {console.log(data);
    this.data = data})
  }
  */

}
```

**moviedetail.component.html**

```
<h2>movie title</h2>

<div class="container">
    <div *ngIf="movie">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <h1>Movie:</h1>
                <b>Title:</b> {{movie.title}}<br>
                <b>Year:</b> {{movie.overview}}<br>
                <p>
                    <button (click)="gotoMovies()">Back</button>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: At first glance, you have waaaay too much code posted. If you want help, you're going to need to narrow down what exactly you think is the problem, and post a short excerpt of that

Comment: You have as mentioned way too much code, but what I instantly see...: `this.movie = this.movieService.getMovie(this.route.snapshot.params['title'])` This is a cold Observable.

Comment: the problem is i dont know where im wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

In the file "movedetail.component.ts" the observable is cold. With observable, the method gets executed only when someone subscribes to it. Also you have assigned a observable directly to an variable here, which is not correct. If you want to assign the value returned from observable to "movie" object, then make the changes as shown below:

movedetail.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.movieService.getMovie(this.route.snapshot.params['title']).subscribe(success=>{this.movie=success;});
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answering back, but when i try to change the code to your suggestion i still get these erros

ERROR in src/app/moviedetail/moviedetail.component.ts(39,3): error TS2322: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Movie'.
  Property 'id' is missing in type 'Subscription'.
src/app/moviedetail/moviedetail.component.ts(39,100): error TS2322: Type 'Movie[]' is not assignable to type 'Movie'.
src/app/moviedetail/moviedetail.component.ts(39,100): error TS2322: Type 'Movie[]' is not assignable to type 'Movie'.
  Property 'id' is missing in type 'Movie[]'.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: @LonelyNeuron, done. I have provided justification on why my answer might work :)